# How to separate String and put into 3 part(combobox, combobox, textfield)

Tags: java, string, combobox

the format of student id is xxXXXxxxxx(xx=2 digit, XXX=3 char, xxxxx=5 digit)
i declare a string as stuid="11WAD03245"
i need to separate stuid to "11" and "WAD" and "03245"
which 11 set to a Jcombobox year and year's model is from 11 to 20
WAD set to another Jcombobox prog and its model is WAD and so on
03245 set into textfield code

Comment: Use `stuid.substring(begin,end)`

Comment: any method on how to write data into Jcombobox?

Comment: `public void insertItemAt(E int index)`

See at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#insertItemAt%28E,%20int%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `substring()` function to get the required part of string.

**Syntax:** `substring(int strartIndex,int endIndex);`

**Example :**

```
String str="hello world";
String word= str.substring(0,5);//returns->  hello
```

---

**Code as Below:**

```
String stuid="11WAD03245";
String stuid1=stuid.substring(0, 2); //returns 11   
String stuid2=stuid.substring(2,5);  //returns WAD 
String stuid3=stuid.substring(5);  //returns 03245
```

Comment: any info on how to write it into Jcombobox? the data neeeded to be read, so please provide the method which can write&read. TQ~

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Java String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
String stuid = "11WAD03245";
int studentId = Integer.parseint(stuid.substring(0,2));
String prog = stuid.substring(2,5);
int model = Integer.parseint(stuid.substring(5,stuid.length()));
```

You can use these variables to set your Jcomboboxes respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.substring(beginIndex, endIndex) this returns new Strings that include your values, and you can parse different kinds of datatypes from them.

Comment: any info on how to write it into Jcombobox? the data neeeded to be read, so please provide the method which can write&read. TQ~

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are correct. I would like to go one step further although this is not exactly what you asked. It seems to me that the format you store the id is very brittle and can be easily improved to support future changes and be easier to work with.

When you rely on indexes you assume that the fields are constant length. If this ever changes- you are in trouble. A more robust approach is to use a separated value list, where you hold a string where the fields are separated by commas or any delimiter.

An example regarding your case: "11,WAD,03245"

This gives you 3 advantages. You do not need to deal with index arithmetic, you are not bound to field lengths and you can **easily** use the split method to obtain every field separately. Like so:

```
    String s = "11,WAD,03245";
    String[] fields = s.split(","); 
    // fields[0] == "11", fields[1] == "WAD", fields[2] == "03245"
```

Naturally you need to deal with cases where the delimiter itself appears in one of the fields but you can usually mitigate that by picking a proper delimiter and using input validation.

I would pick this approach even if I could rely on constant fields lengths only because it is easier to manipulate.

Comment: any info on how to write it into Jcombobox? the data neeeded to be read, so please provide the method which can write&read. TQ~